# Why do I get the IMDB result translated in Romanian?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

```
HttpWebRequest WebReq;
HttpWebResponse WebResp;
Stream Answer;
StreamReader _Answer;    
string ResponseOutput;

WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(imdb.url);
WebReq.KeepAlive = false;
WebReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.2.4) Gecko/20100611 Firefox/3.6.4";                
WebReq.Method = "GET";    
WebReq.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");
WebReq.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
try
{
    using (WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse())
    {
        Answer = WebResp.GetResponseStream();
        _Answer = new StreamReader(Answer);
        ResponseOutput = _Answer.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
catch (WebException ex) {return null;}
```

Why do i get the page translated in romanian ? If i call this code with `http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1606378/` i get the response containing `<title>Si mai greu de ucis (2013) - IMDb</title>` instead of `<title>A Good Day to Die Hard (2013) - IMDb</title>` ?

Comment: set the http accept language header and itll work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works just fine for me, but I suspect they are doing a geolocation to get your language in absence of a language header.

I would suggest giving an `Accept-Language` header with `en` as the value:

```
WebReq.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en");
```

Comment: @RobertHarvey I was thinking the same thing :) rhose87: This should solve your problem "permanently".

Comment: "for now" = i am an entry level developer, so i think i will have another issues soon :-D